# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, в templates не читается home.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Шёл пошагово по книге Spring in Action, самый первый урок, java 18, parent spring-boot-starter-parent 3.0.3
[image: Структура проекта]

Когда создаю и загружаю проект, то выдаёт Whitelabel Error Page

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-ccloud</name>
    <description>taco-ccloud</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

После смены версии Spring boot с 3.0.3 на 3.0.0 всё начало нормально работать